# Is the Name property of output of Group-Object always string?

Tags: powershell

The following script can transform(pivot) the array by the third column (x, y). However, it needs to concatenate the first two columns for the group-object command. And then the `Name` of the output need to be split to get the original values.

It can be error prone if the data has the separator character. And it seems not performance optimized since extra string concatenation/split actions are needed. Is it a more direct way (like SQL group clause) in powershell?

```
$a =@('a','b','x',10), 
    @('a','b','y',20), 
    @('c','e','x',50), 
    @('c','e','y',30)

# $a | % { "[$_]"}

$a | %{ 
    new-object PsObject -prop @{
        label = "$($_[0]),$($_[1])" # Concatenate for grouping 
        value = @{ $_[2] = $_[3] }
        } 
} | 
group label | % {
    $l = @($_.Name -split ",") + # then split to restore
         @($_.Group.value.x, $_.Group.value.y) 
    "[$l]"
}
```

Comment: Yes, its always a string

Comment: So there is no way to do SQL-like group by multiple columns using powershell?

Comment: You can use an expression to control the grouping. In the expression you can use whatever logic/code you want.

Comment: @EBGreen It still needs to parse the string of `Name` later to get the array values? So it has little benefit to group on expression?

Comment: Show what you would want the output to look like. I'm not understanding what you are looking for.

Comment: The code in my question does what I need. Just try to see if there is a better way to do grouping in powershell without extra string manipulations.

Comment: Use `Values` property of `GroupInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the "Name" property of `GroupInfo` is always a string.

The easiest way to find the distinct values is to *sample* the first item in each group:

```
$a |Group-Object -Property {$_[0]},{$_[1]} |ForEach-Object {
    $Group = $_.Group

    # The first item in each group
    $SampleItem = $Group | Select-Object -First 1

    # Now we can inspect the key values, $SampleItem[0] and $SampleItem[1]
    Write-Host ('This group has {0} and {1} as primary keys:' -f $SampleItem[0..1]) -ForegroundColor Green

    $Group |ForEach-Object { 
        # echo each array in group
        Write-Host ($_ -join ' ')
    }
}
```

[image: Yay!]